# HTML Editor Extender displays HTML on navigate backwards

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, html-editor, obout

I have an Ajax Control Toolkit HtmlEditorExtender control on my ASP.NET forms page.

First I add some formatted text (including `<br />`'s by pressing cariage return) and then navigate away from the page by following some link. Then I use the browser to navigate backwards. I would expect that the message should then be either empty or display correctly, but it displays the unencoded html.

I can't find any reports of known bugs about this, does anyone know about a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This **HtmlEditorExtender** is not a product of **OBOUT**. It does not work properly.
**OBOUT INC.** has made the **HTMLEditor** control for this toolkit, it's already obsolete there.

Use the real **OBOUT AJAX HTML Editor**. You can test it here: [Full screen enabled Editor](http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/examples/Appearance_FullScreen.aspx)

Another good example of customization (online translation): [Google AJAX Language API implementation](http://www.obout.com/Obout.Ajax.UI/HTMLEditor/examples/Customize_CustomSelectButton.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Victor, have updated my post. I do not have the option of changing the control.